# Remove products from shopping cart - Website Odoo 9

Tags: python, xml, odoo-9

I want to know how can i create a model (or extend existing one) for deleting a products from the Shopping cart in Odoo9.

The problem is described on the picture. I should add a a button and when i press it will delete the product completely doesn't matter which quantity is given.

Thank you in advance,

Kind regards,
Igor

[image: Shopping cart]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A product is removed from your cart when its quantity reaches 0**. Therefore try to use that function that already exists rather than creating your own javascript.

You can insert your button on `website_sale/views/templates.xml` On the template with the `id="cart"` and when clicked it should call a js script.

See on `wesbsite_sale/static/src/js/website_sale.js` check the part that starts with

```
$(oe_website_sale).on("change", ".oe_cart input.js_quantity[data-product-id]", function () {
```

This piece of code observes for changes in the quantity of the products and if the quantity reaches 0 it removes the whole line.

**So you can change the quantity on the line you want to remove to 0 and the already existing code will remove the line.**