# Add delete option in lines as like we are having in shopping cart

Tags: odoo, delete-row, odoo-12, odoo-website

I have structure as like we have in shopping cart with products.

Following is detailed information about my structure :

I have created one page in website, in which there is a button to add lines where user will enter details like product and quantity.
But there is not any option to remove  line.
So I want to add a option to remove any particular line, for that I will add "Trash" icon so user can click on it and delete that line.

Can anyone please help me to make it done as like cart?

[image]

Comment: visit this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41877376/remove-products-from-shopping-cart-website-odoo-9

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code in your question so I can't figure it out your classes or functions name, but you could try something like this:

```
def btn_delete_line(self):
    res = super(YourClassName, self).unlink()
    return res
```